# write result of SPARQL to file in java

Tags: java, file, sparql, jena, fuseki

I use fuseki server as embedded server in java and I get SPARQL results with following piece of code:

```java
public static void execSelectAndPrint(FileWriter fw, String serviceURI, String query) throws IOException {
    QueryExecution q = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(serviceURI,query);
    ResultSet results = q.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.outputAsCSV(System.out, results);
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
        RDFNode x = soln.get("x");
        System.out.println(x);
        fw.append(x.toString());        
    }
    fw.close();
}
```

it prints results to console correctly but it can write to file. I want to write result of SPARQL query to a csv file.

Comment: The call to `ResultSetFormatter.outputAsCSV` will read all the results and the loop following will write nothing. To use results twice, use `ResultSet.makeRewindable` and call `.reset()` to go back to the beginning and start iterating again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Writer`s can produce problems with character translation which is why the API prefers `OutputStream` and so using `FileOutputStream` will work.

Otherwise, output to bytes using `ByteArrayOutputStream`, convert to a string and write the string.

But be careful about character sets. Most SPARQL related formats are UTF-8, not the platform native character set.